# Is there a way to limit search highlight length?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm indexing e-mails using search highlihts.

Is there any way to tell Azure Search how many characters before and after highlight I would like to receive?

In my application on left side of the screen I would like to show highlight and after clicking it I would like to show whole e-mail on the right side. But the problem is that even for some long e-mails highlights often contain full message body. Ideally I would like to see only 2-4 lines above and below found string.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think this is configurable. Depending on the language analyzer that you are using will depend on the delimiter that's used to decide how this text is cropped and returned. You can always manipulate the returned highlighted result yourself to only display a few lines.

Comment: I have the same issue and it's a real shame. Sometimes I get a ton of text coming back. I tried truncating the text as proposed but that can cause the highlighted term is cut out :(